# Can't display anything through homepage text editor

Tags: php, css, html

I'm trying to use my homepage text editor but nothing will display when I use it. I've tried using a high `z-index` but nothing will display.

Page [here](https://4309.co.uk)

I've had to resort to using css to display text or images, or widgets.

Where would I find the php which might control it and what specifically would I be looking for?

I've looked through my css but can't identity anything which would stop it displaying.

The only clue is that when I look at my source code to find the image or element which has ostensibly been published, nothing shows up.

The theme is Shapely by Colorlib and i don't think any plugins are interfering as the page just won't publish anything I put in either the visual or text editor on that page.

Comment: Your homepage probably isn't populated through the editor. Check your theme's support resources or contact the author.

Comment: You should provide more details about the WordPress theme you are using and the plugins attached to it. Afterwards, you could check if you have ``<?php the_content(); ?>`` called on either front-page.php, index.php or page.php or any other page that could be linked to you homepage.

Comment: Looked in index.php, page.php, header.php, don't have home.php, couldn't find `the_content`